# How can I avoid text wrapping in nested position: absolute elements?

Tags: html, css, css-position, absolute

In my app, there are two nested "position: absolute" elements, and the inner element contains some dynamically loaded text.

The problem is that the text is wrapping along every word, whereas I'd prefer it didn't wrap at all.  The issue is that `inner` is absolute, and thus out of flow, so the computed width of `outer` is 0, which means that the text is overflowing outside the bounds of its parent, so it wraps.

Here's what's happening: https://jsfiddle.net/y9pLgzub/

And here's what I want to happen, except without the explicit sizing: https://jsfiddle.net/pv2g3rwo/

Is there any way I can maintain the HTML structure (two nested absolute divs), but make it so the text in `inner` doesn't wrap?  Ideally the outer element would expand in size to fit the entire inner element, despite it being "position: absolute".

Answer (score 1):

Since both .inner and .outer are `position: absolute`, the .outer cannot expand in size according to child. The dimensions have to be explicitly stated.

As for the word wrap problem. you can try `white-space: nowrap;`

```css
.outer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
      asdf asdf
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by including `whitespace: nowrap;` in `.inner{}`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe less is more: When using padding on the outer instead of offsetting the inner, the calculation should be about right:

```
.outer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px 0 0 10px;
}

.inner {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
      asdf asdf
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/du2f8tsb/